# use of the word they're

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

Proper use of the word they're in a sentence. Example

> 1. **They're** camping out

or

> 2. **They are** camping out

or

> 3. **Their** camping out

Which usage is correct? Is using the word "they're" when referring to more than two people correct?

Comment: **They're** and **their** are pronounced the same (at least in most dialects), but don't confuse them!  *They're* means *they are*.  *Their* means "belonging to them".  Even a lot of native speakers get this wrong!

Answer (score 4):

**They're** is the abbreviated form of **they are**.

This form is used more in informal writing and when reflecting how people speak. In formal contexts, such as business letters, you should prefer **they are**.

Both forms are perfectly correct. Which one you choose really depends on the context.

So you are more likely to say:

> They're camping out

than

> They are camping out

and if you were surprised when your friend told you that your parents were at the top of a tree, you would exclaim: **They are!** rather than **they're**.

Both forms can refer to two or more people. In fact, if you should see a tent pitched in a field, you might well remark that **they're camping out** when you don't know whether you referring to one camper or half a dozen.

**Their camping out...** is quite different. You would be most likely to use this construction when you wanted to talk about the implications of people camping out in particular circumstances, for example:

> Their camping out in this weather is not a good idea.

or

> > Her parents did not approve of their camping out during the winter.

Here **their camping out** means people's act or habit of camping out.